# Can I add "cosmetic" edges to a cytoscape dagre layout?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm using cytoscape with a dagre layout to generate my graph and I want to include extra edges (depicted in red below) to effectively "annotate" the graph. However, this doesn't work the way I would like it to because the dagre layout takes all edges into account when generating the graph.

I know I can use a "preset" layout to achieve this behaviour, however there are distinct benefits to using the dagre layout including proper expand-collapse functionality via the expand-collapse extension.

I also tried playing around with the "edgeWeight" option within the dagre layout to no effect. Does anyone have any recommendations? Thanks!

[image: cytoscape question]

Comment: This is for cytoscape.js, not cytoscape so I would recommend changing your tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by filtering out the edge before rendering the layout:

```
var processedElements = this.cy
  .elements()
  // Filter out edges we don't want contributing to the layout of
  // of the graph
  .filter(el => !el.hasClass("unbundled-bezier-1"))

var layout = processedElements.layout({
  name: "dagre",
  rankDir: "LR"
})

layout.run();
```